# Installing gedit 3.11.2

Tags: gedit, make, configure

I am trying to install gedit 3.11.2 from:

https://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit

for some reason, it does not work on my ubuntu 13.10

the file `./configure` is not found.

i followed the steps in the `README` file:

```
  % tar Jxf gedit-3.11.2.tar.xz         # unpack the sources
  % cd gedit-3.11.2             # change to the toplevel directory
  % ./configure                 # run the `configure' script
  % make                    # build gedit
  [ Become root if necessary ]
  % make install                # install gedit
```

but then, the configure is not found. Am I missing something here?

Comment: yep, no configure file. You need to file a bug report with the maintainers. You *might* be able to run the autogen.sh . Try running `chomd a+x autogen.sh && autogen.sh`. then continue with `./configure` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the package from:

http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gedit/3.11/

You might missing some lib. You can get them by installing them:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install intltool
sudo apt-get install itstool
sudo apt-get install libxml2 libglib2.0-dev libxml2-dev libxml2-utils
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libgtksourceviewmm-3.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-dev
sudo apt-get install gsettings-desktop-schemas-dev   
sudo apt-get install libgtkspell3-3-dev libgtkspell3-3-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-dev
sudo apt-get install gtk+3.0
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtk-3.0
```

I had an issue getting `gtksourceview`, I had to install it manually:

http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/gtksourceview/3.11/

same deal:

```
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

**INSTALLING Gedit**

Then, once everything is completed, you can run in the gedit folder:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

NOTE: you might some graphic issues with the new GTK library. Check you drivers (nvidia or ati for example) or play with the "appearance" settings.

Comment: I've always liked "apt-get build-dep" to install dependencies so in this case "apt-get build-dep gedit".  It will get all the dependencies you need.  Of course it only knows about dependencies for the version in the ubuntu repo, but I find it to usually get right set.